# In what order do you half and double when damage is both halved and doubled?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, vulnerability

Suppose a creature is vulnerable to radiant damage, and is beginning its turn in the area of effect of [Moonbeam](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Moonbeam#content). It will be taking radiant damage, and the damage roll is a 13. It succeeds on its saving throw, so the damage is halved, but it is vulnerable to radiant damage, so the damage is doubled.

Is the damage first halved, giving 6, and then doubled, giving 12? Or is it doubled first, then halved to give 13? Or do the effects cancel, for a total damage of 13?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the marked question. I've edited the title, which may have caused the confusion.

Comment: The linked duplicate seems appropriate regarding vulnerability, given there's a stated order of operations within the rules regarding it. So your example is answered by the linked question. If there's no stated order of operations (such that perhaps the damage is being doubled for reasons other than vulnerability), the easiest method is to simply have them "cancel", similarly to advantage and disadvantage.

Comment: there was a different post linked previously, this one definitely does answer it. thanks!